# Convert CSV data to a matrix to a heatmap in R

Tags: r, csv, heatmap

Doing some visualizations for a paper I'm writing and am stuck in trasfering data from a CSV-loaded table to a matrix (to be able to plot a heatmap from it afterwards).

I'm doing this:

```
dta.tesiscsv<- read.csv("dtatesis.csv", header=TRUE)
```

to load a data sample that looks like this:

```
Col,Row,Kf
1,1,100
1,2,97.14285714
2,1,100 
...,...,...
```

but am kind of lost on the next step (creating an empty matrix and transfering data from the table to it based on a formula):

```
X<- matrix(nrow= 48, ncol=12)
X[dta.test[,c(1:2)]] <- dta.test$Kf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `acast` from `reshape2` package to get the data in the matrix form you desire.

```
require(reshape2)
acast(dta.test, Row ~ Col, value.var = "Kf")
```

This'll fill missing values with `NA`. If you want to fill them, for example, with 0 instead, then,

```
acast(dta.test, Row ~ Col, value.var = "Kf", fill = 0)
```

would accomplish that. You can wrap this around with `heatmap(.)` to get the heatmap.

Answer (score 1):

How about (which should make sense if there is *one* row per Col/Row-combination):

```
dta.tesiscsv <- read.table(text="Col,Row,Kf
1,1,100
1,2,97.14285714
2,1,100",h=T,sep=",")

X <- tapply(dta.tesiscsv[,3],dta.tesiscsv[,2:1],head,1)
heatmap(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're real close.  To use matrix indexing, the indices have to be a matrix, not a data.frame.

```
X[as.matrix(dta.test[,c(1:2)])] <- dta.test$Kf
```